# Not being able to "make" in Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, wget

Hi so i am trying to install the commands `wget` and `with-readline` for use with Mac OS X's terminal. The configuration seems to work fine for both even though i am required to specify for the first one, `host= i686-apple`.

When i get to the `make` part of the installation, the output is as follows.

**For wget:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQb3a.jpg

**for with-readline**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqnD7.jpg

so does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably something very similar to [this](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.lisp/problems-building-clisp-2.35-on-os-x/699960). I'd suspect OS X has a readline older than what with-readline wants. You can solve this by installing readline from Macports or fink or homebrew... your OS X package manager of choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, here's what I've got.

Checking the readline version control history, [rl_gnu_readline_p](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/diff/readline.h?id=2916980bde9ae4d8b8e9d60062660bdca947f56e) was [added in 4.1](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/commit/?id=2916980bde9ae4d8b8e9d60062660bdca947f56e) which was released in 2000.  OS X 10.7 *should* have that... but it actually fakes libreadline by linking to libedit which is some BSD emulation library.  I guess they're avoiding getting that icky GNU license on OS X.  Seeing as how rl_gnu_readline_p is [the "I'm really readline" variable](https://web.archive.org/web/20121023033813/http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_28.html), it makes sense that would be missing.

I would suggest using a 3rd party package system to install the read readline, such as [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/), [fink](https://www.finkproject.org/) or [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).  Then build your software off of that.

Comment: thanks for the pointing to homebrew it looks awesome. Although that doesn't really fix the problem, since there are a number of problems that arose when did `brew doctor`. So many that it has led me to completely reinstall MacOSX. Too many problems with permissions and paths that is. Also since i partially installed Macports just before that i also further scrambled the ability of Brew's formulae from working.

Comment: [MacPorts can quickly be uninstalled by deleting `/opt/local`](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html).  Homebrew has an [uninstall script](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/FAQ).  Generally they're really good about keeping themselves isolated and shouldn't touch the system (there are small exceptions like startup items).  An OS reinstall is not necessary if they get messed up.  Personally I use MacPorts, though most of my alpha geek friends use Homebrew. Pick one and slug it out, they're necessary to make OS X a real Unix environment.